# Symfony React Login Authorization Blocked By CORS Policy

Tags: reactjs, symfony, cors, symfony6

Versions :
SF : 6.3
API Platform : 3.1
JWT : Lexik 2.19
React : 18.2

As you see, is a fresh installation of SF app with API Platform and react, that use JWT to login users.

**I have a standard config projects without docker. Just symfony serve and npm run start**

**With POSTMAN everything sounds good, I can set login/password and I get token and refreshToken as response.**

When I try to do the same thing with axios in react I have this message :

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login_check' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.*

I know this is a common errors that exist everywhere but I can't find what is wrong

**SF**
*Security.yaml*

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    login:
        pattern: ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        json_login:
            check_path: /api/login_check
            username_path: email
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
    api:
        pattern: ^/api
        stateless: true
        entry_point: jwt
        jwt: ~
        refresh_jwt:
            check_path: /api/token/refresh # or, you may use the `api_refresh_token` route name

    main:
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider
```

**API** *nelmio_cors.yaml*

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        origin_regex: true
        allow_origin: ['*'] #['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
        expose_headers: ['Link']
        max_age: 3600
    paths:
        '^/': null
```

**API** *routes.yaml*

```
api_login_check:
    path: /api/login_check

api_refresh_token:
    path: /api/token/refresh
```

**React** *axios*

```
import axios from "axios";

const entrypoint = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT;

export const post = async (iri, object) => {
 try {
  return await axios.post(entrypoint + iri, object, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

};

**Thanks For Help !!**

Comment: UP :( please help, I m blocked